# Matrices on the hypercube

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $A_{ij}$ be a real $N\times N$ matrix, with the property that:
$$x_i \sum_j A_{ij} x_j > 0$$
for any $\mathbf x \in \{\pm1\}^{N}$ lying on the $N$-hypercube. That is, $A$ maps vertices of the hyper-cube to points lying in the same orthant.

Is there any name for matrices of this sort? Any further properties they might satisfy?

Comment: Do they pop up in some nice context or is it just a random question (which I enjoy) ?